# Should I work on XML simultaneously while I work on the Java coding for developing an Android App?

Tags: java, android, xml, list, user-interface

First off, I would like to make clear, that I am SUPER NEW TO THIS!! I suck at Java/developing, but I am very enthusiastic to learn.

I have a project in mind, an informative Android app. I think I have an idea of how I want it structered:

First View = list of 50 objects

Once you click on one of those objects it will provide another list of information of THOSE objects.

I understand that the Java coding is what I'd need to put the data there, but I also know that I'd have to be a little familiar with XML to actually make it look pretty. Am I supposed to be running back and forth to both the XML layouts and the Java code at the same time? Can I come back to fix up the XML later?

Do I have the right idea on how to structure an App that just lists tons of info?

Comment: Check out mine - github.com/jordanbtahabsim/Family-Tree

Comment: I've been looking over your code for the past 2 hours, and I must say, just by looking at things and googling certain components I have learned QUITE A BIT!! I don't really get the public class Character extends Activity bit though. Do I need to type this EVERY time I want a new View?

Comment: Yes that means its viewable. Like the tree class I didnt

Comment: You should download/fork it and edit it yourself!

Comment: Well, right now I'm at my job, remoting in to my PC at home to work on my own code so doing that stuff is kinda not an option lol. I really don't want to be a bother to you, but do you think you can help me with my code at all? We chat a little bit outside of Stack Overflow? I'm only asking you because you seem to have the closest structure to what I want, only my app isn't going to have room for inputting data by the user (that's more or less the part of your code that's throwing me off)

Comment: Sounds good how to you want to communicate?

Comment: IS it okay for us to post our personal e-mails on this site? I just joined!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you jump into developing Android applications, I would start with learning the concepts of Object Oriented Programming. An eagerness to learn is fantastic, but it is half the battle. Going straight into app development with no programming background will likely hinder your enthusiasm. Start with the basics: what is a variable, function/method, etc. Then get into classes, polymorphism, OOP concepts, etc.

As far as XML, it is a simple markup language. Once you have some programming experience(or even without), figuring out how XML works is not too difficult IMO.

Comment: Thank you for your input, much appreciated! So I bought Head First Java last month. I've made some progress, I understand (instance)variables, functions/method's, ArrayLists basic OOP concepts, classes and such. So far, I'm loving the book! I feel what I'm trying to do with the Android app correlates with the direction the book is taking me as well. I admit I'm still jumping the gun here, but all I really need is an idea of how I should structure it. From what I understand, every "view" is a screen on android. I just need to learn how to connect my data with certain views. Again, thanks!

Comment: Very good, you are much better off than I thought. Just stick with it and make use of all resources. Like I said, there really isn't much difficulty to understanding an XML file. Good luck!